# Jquery mobile splitview $.mobile.changePage not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, ipad

Hi I am using Jquery mobile splitview as given in the libraryhttps://github.com/asyraf9/jquery-mobile/.

I have two pages in the left A and B panel and two pages  C and D in the right panel.
Initially I render page A and C in left and right panel respectively. Now on click on a link I want to change the left panel from A to B and in right panel C to D

Change is not working completely its only changing the left panel not the page in right panel where the above anchor is placed.

Note that the link or button above is present in the right pane always. If I use

Comment: Is theer any difference if I just do show/hide divs containing the pages instead of using $.mobile.changePage ? I have to do so because  $.mobile.changePage is not working

Comment: not completely sure if this helps but just fyi, if you are using any javascript on the pages called from changepage method, make sure you specify the methods within the <div data-role="page"...>..

Answer (score 0):

do a .refresh() after link click/anything that triggers the change in the splitview.

Comment: Somehow $("#panelID").live('refresh'); or  $("#panelID").trigger('refresh'); did not work. I tried $("#panelID").trigger('create');  and $("#targetpageid").trigger('refresh'); also after calling mobile page change. Looks like I have to get rid of panes and move to a completely new html page.

Answer (score 0):

there is a context loading option in splitview. Why not use this?

I can't find the sample page anymore, but I'm using the same logic in my script, so... if you can't find it, try something like this:

1) give your links context attributes:

```
<a href="#some" data-panel="menu" data-context="#otherPage" data-context-panel="main">click me</a>
```

2) Listen for clicks on these context links like so:

```
$(document).bind( "click", function( event ) {
  console.log("click registered");
  var link = $( self.findClosestLink(event.target) );

  if ( !link || event.which > 1) {
     return;
     }

  console.log( link );
  console.log( link.jqmData('context') );

  // context routine fires with context links
  if ( link.length === 1 && link.jqmData('context') ) {
     // fire your context function, RENAME THIS
     console.log("firing context routine");
     self.context( link );
     }
```

3) Put a context function somewhere:

```
 context: function( object ) {

       var self = this,
           $context = object,
           $targetPanelID = $context.jqmData('context-panel');

       console.log("contextpage="+$context.href+"  contextPanel="+targetPanelID);

       // make sure the pageContainer is correctly set for the 2nd transition
       $.mobile.pageContainer = $('div:jqmData(panel="'+$targetPanelID+'")');

       // context changePage
       $.mobile.changePage( $( $context.jqmData('context') ), { transition:'slide', changeHash:true, fromHashChange: false, pageContainer: $.mobile.pageContainer });
       };
```

4) Add the JQM findclosestLink function (I forgot)

```
  findClosestLink: function (ele) {
     var self = this;
     while (ele){
     if (ele.nodeName.toLowerCase() == "a"){
        break;
        }
    ele = ele.parentNode;
    return ele;
    }
```

Your link will fire the first changePage, your context function will fire the second changePage. Depending on where you use this, your context changePage call will also trigger another hashChange event, which JQM may not block (every changePage also fires a hashChange which is blocked by JQM using **ignoreNextHashChange** - check the source).

So you may have to do something like this after making your second call to ensure the hashChange is blocked:

```
  $.mobile.ignoreNextHashChange = true;
```

The whole thing is working inside my [multiview](http://www.stokkers.mobi/valuables/multiview/show/index.html) plugin, BUT the plugin is not finished, buggy and I haven't had the time to work on it lately. Context is working though, so you might just pull it out and use it as you need.

Cheers!

Comment: What is  self.findClosestLink ? I replaced it with "jQuery(this).closest" still did not work.

Comment: Okei , I got the definition of findClosestLink  from your plugin site.

Comment: However the clicks are not doing anything . No error in error console. I am assuming <a href="#page to navigate" data-panel="data id property of the panel in which the targate page is " data-context="#page in the other panel" data-context-panel="the other panel">click me</a>

Comment: you may need to use this function, too in your setup. Yup. Wait I paste above.

Comment: Thanks Frequent, as I said above the click is not doing anything , see my last comment. Are my assumptions right ?

Comment: Hey Neil. correct, your link has the regular splitview attributes = page to load and panel. Plus the context page and panel. I updated my code with some consoles. See if they fire.

Comment: After clicking it prints the following only --
[09:44:18.300] click registered
[09:44:18.311] [object Object] 
[09:44:18.319] undefined

Comment: Am I doing something wrong that it is not able to get the context , the only change I did is to define the function like function context( object ) { instead of context: function( object )

Comment: Are above functions should be inside some particular page ? for me all JS are in Head and I am not sure of the "self" is correct while getting the link